# Am I being too snippy -- or how should one treat questions where OP doesn't check the JavaScript console?

Tags: discussion

Lately I've been finding LOTS of JavaScript questions where had the OP even looked at the error console it would have explained what was going on.

I want to encourage people to read the console, so I let them know that they could have (should have) done so.

This particular question was my latest victim:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37380203/jquery-querybuilder-not-working-with-https/37380508#37380508

So.. am I being too gruff in my answers, or should I assume that StackOverflow's target audience doesn't have the experience to even know there is an error console available?

Comment: You wisely steered clear of making any *ad hominem* attacks. I think your tone is perfectly appropriate.

Comment: There's always the downvote button... "this question does not show any research effort"

Comment: Two words: Play Nice.

Comment: I'd note that this is not just JS. There are a lot of crap debugging questions in all sorts of languages, where OP either doesn't even disclose the specific error message, or doesn't try to understand it even when it's crystal clear. This is a general symptom of askers being chronically lazy (or stupid), partially due to the usual help vampire vs repwhore feedback loop. Gruffness is great, what they deserve is downvote+close vote(no MCVE/clear error) until they start to show at least the first signs of trying to solve their own problems.

Comment: I think that your answer was rather polite. But people get triggered off weird things; I was trying to help someone despite their off-topic question and they accused me of trolling by posting on meta. Apparently, I made a stupid suggestion because the question was well outside my skill area. You can find it somewhere here, I responded to their meta-dramatic question.

Comment: I'm on the verge of RSI just from typing 'have you checked the console?' 5 million times.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - as have I from 'what does the debugger say' in `c` tagged questions

Comment: Your question lacks any indication of whether you are simply feeling bad about it or if someone called you out.  Either way, I tend to believe that when I suspect I've been a jerk, I probably have.  Beyond that, this is a site for professional information sharing.  So treating people like professionals that should have a clue isn't off base, IMO.

Comment: May I just say that it is very encouraging to me to see you more experienced guys actually discussing such things while helping us less experienced folks?  It's nice to know that you really are trying and making conscientious effort.  I'm one of those that often gets the "smack down" in just the way you are describing here.  But, I come to SO, not just for answers, but to LEARN.  And SO is about the best source of knowledge, so long as you keep in mind that some of us don't want another "justanswer.com"  We like to *learn* from you guys.

Comment: Have you been to the [android] and [php] tags? There are so many lazy question askers there that does not even know how to start debugging. Teaching these take time and energy and I can't blame you for being annoyed. In my case, when I know I am annoyed, I stop commenting and just downvote/flag to close. I always keep in mind the phrase on our [Be Nice Policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice): *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does*

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace  The truth is: I want to help people and I *enjoy* teaching coding, but yea, people have to want to learn.  In this medium, the only hint that I get about a person's desire to learn in the effort they put into the question.

Comment: One problem is lots of them have no idea console is there or if they see something are not able to comprehend what they see

Comment: I  can't see the original post. It's been removed. But what if someone just doesn't know about the console? I think it's easy to forget what it's like to be a complete beginner, following the JavaScript in 24 hours, and not having any idea of where to turn. Sometimes what might look like laziness is just ignorance. Maybe just a polite '

Comment: I often leave a comment explaining how to gather basic information ("Hit F12 to open the console", "Edit the question and copy the exact error message") just to see how the OP answers all comments but mine. A while later, a question with just a bunch of code gets accepted. You can imagine how frustrating that is.

Comment: I personally often find questions to which I immediately know the answer but I believe the OP could find it himself if I give him some hint. You know, teach a man how to fish...So I usually try to do that, and would say something like "does the console give you any indication about the error? Press F12 to see it".
The problem being, most of the time, reputation-wh**es will have already left 3 or 4 answers...

Comment: A considerable proportion of C problems could be found by compiling with `-Wall` - same issue.

Comment: reading the above comments, I just want to point out that, being inside javascript from "quite" a while, I sometimes feel disappointed that a user is asking without checking his console. I've been a newbie too, but if you actually reach stackoverflow and you actually ask a question in stackoverflow, the chance that you didn't yet encounter any tutorial / answer that either explains or just points to the word "console" should be close to ZERO. As far as I can tell, almost every javascript tutorial / answer involves the console, that's just mandatory. Anyway, that's something to discuss about.

Comment: remember that stackoverflow is a platform created for helping people and spreading knowledge not for blaming them

Answer (score 234):

Overall, your message is fine. The only thing I would change is this

> Had you looked at the error console, it would have informed you what the issue was.

to this

> If you look at the error console, it can tell you what the issue is.

By phrasing it in the past tense, you're telling the OP that they should have already known this. As hard as it is to believe, they might not know about the error console. Nobody knows about it until somebody tells them. By phrasing your message slightly differently, you change your message from mildly annoyed to a friendly tip that the OP can remember in the future.

Comment: I would take a middle ground--assume they don't know about the error console but tell them they really need to do that from now on.  *If you look at the error console, it can tell you what the issue is.* **This should always be your first step in debugging.**

Comment: @rsjaffe Yes, that's the next sentence in the original message, which I would leave unchanged.

Comment: When mentioning this, I usually link "[error console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)" to a webmasters post explaining how to view it in various browsers. Obviously, canned snippets are helpful here.

Comment: Amazing what a difference in tone that slight change makes.

Comment: @PaulRoub That's a great resource to link to. I was looking for something like that in the various error console related tag wikis on SO. I'm glad we have that covered.

Comment: I like to wrap up my answers with  "**Pro tip**: always blah blah blah" in these sorts of cases; it's polite and makes readers think they're getting inside information.  It works better than writing "you should have known this you n00b."

Comment: Your advice is excellent.  Instead of promoting a mild level of anger or annoyance, it promotes acceptance, tolerance, and understanding... qualities in short supply in the programming world.  Now the next question: How do I say *that* without coming across as a little annoyed?

Comment: The other reason for changing the phrasing is that English is not everyone's native language. Bill's change uses more common phrasing, a bit friendlier to ESL folks. (Except I'd say "...it will tell you...")

Comment: "By phrasing it in the past tense, you're telling the OP that they should have already known this" And maybe they should? I don't know anything about the technical specifics here, but judging by the OP this is some beginner-level mistake similar to RTFM. If so, then maybe the question should have been closed in the first place.

Comment: SO used to be a place for programmers, where questions needed research effort and people needed a minimum of knowledge about the topic. It has transformed into "interactive beginner tutorial", where anyone can post any kind of crap. On the side-lines stands the meta crap-huggers and defend everyone's right to post crap. If I post a question about why my screen is black when I run "hello world", must someone really post an answer and teach me that I need to power up my monitor? Shouldn't a professional or enthusiast programmer already know such things?

Comment: @Lundin That question is closed, and downvoted, and deleted. That doesn't mean people need to be snippy about it in comments and answers. Telling people to RTFM has never been acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No it isn't acceptable. But your first reaction to this seems to be "maybe you could have worded it differently as you are implicitly suggesting RTFM", instead of "maybe you shouldn't have answered this question in the first place, but made sure it got closed, as it lacks research effort". The snippy answer was generated by a crappy question. Changing the tone of answers is well and good, but it doesn't solve anything. People are annoyed for a reason. The focus for future improvement of the site should instead be: why do crappy "gimme-newbie-tutorial" questions end up on SO in the first place?

Comment: @Lundin This Meta question was about the tone of the answer, so that's what I focused on. You're free to focus on improving whatever aspect of SO you'd like.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard "Instead of promoting a mild level of anger or annoyance, it promotes acceptance, tolerance, and understanding... qualities in short supply in the programming world" is just "It promotes acceptance, tolerance, and understanding... qualities that we want to emphasize in the world of programming." Deleting negative thoughts are like deleting code we're proud of but is no longer necessary. Which is all of my code....

Comment: @DanRosenstark I like everything you said there.  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard being positive is so fun!

Comment: "Nobody knows about it until somebody tells them." Once upon a time, there did exist people who actively researched on their own...

Comment: I admit that I am often coming across unfriendly, but secretly admire those who manage not to do that. It just seems that everytime I promise myself to try harder, I run into ten consecutive people who reply back, clearly telling me that they don't give a damn and just want to see code. I know the next person doesn't deserve the frustration gathered from whom I "helped" previously, but the struggle, on the helping side, is real. To me, anyway.

Answer (score 15):

Things to think about:

People only learn as fast as they can.

Don't confuse a sub-optimal editorial or composition skills for a lack of knowledge or sincerity.

If a question irritates you, don't try to answer it - just move on and have a better day.

If all you have is a good guess at an answer, don't answer.

I have used Stack Overflow for quite some time, but only recently began contributing.  I find wading through many useless answers much more frustrating than ill-formed questions.

Remember, people are looking for technical help, not vocational counseling.

Comment: Maybe "If all you have is a good guess at an answer, leave a comment" would do as well?

Answer (score 0):

@jeremy-j-starcher, you are a lot more experienced on SO than I am, so it's a bit hard for me to be so bold as to try and answer this, but this is a question/answer forum, so here I go.

The Raison d'être for Stack Overflow and the like is the fact that people do not know what they don't and need help learning. I believe we should have the same attitude as one one would towards a child learning a new language. If my son/daughter said "waked" instead of "woke" - at the age of, say 2 - I would correct and even encourage him/her rather than getting mad. If they do the same thing at age 25, my reaction would be predictably different. One factor to consider might be the users' overall reputation or a quick look at how much they have posted under a given subject.The lower it is the more forgiving we should be.

I know looking at a user profile is more work than just answering a question, but I think it would lead to a more balanced reaction - it does for me, anyway.

Comment: "The Raison d'être for Stack Overflow and the like is the fact that people do not know what they don't and need help learning" -- Alas, that is a misunderstanding and one of the major problems that StackOver faces.  It is *not* an educational site or a learning resource center.  It is, by its very definition, a 'Question and Answer' site.  Come with good questions, get good answers.  It isn't for handholding, tutorials and basic educational training.  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @jeremy-j-starcher, fair enough. We should still be cognizant of the skill level of the person asking the question as the degree of OP's experience changes the question and the directness of our feedback should reflect that. That is my opinion.